# How do I create a new list from a list and append something to the list

Tags: python, list, append

I've been struggling for the last 5 hours trying to figure this question out.

**"using the `cities` list, we want to create a list of the names for each city. Loop through each city and append it's name (`'City'`) to the `city_names` list."**

```
{'City': 'Buenos Aires', 'Country': 'Argentina', 'Population': 2891000, 'Area': 4758}, {'City': 'Toronto', ....and so on
```

What I tried:

```
city_names = []
for city in cities:
    city_names.append(city['City'])
print(city_names)
```

I only have a loose idea of what it wants me to do. I'm assuming it wants me to do 'Buenos Ares City, Mexico City', etc. I'm floundering around like a blind man in a dark cave. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: do you want to create one list that contains all the city name? and from what? do you have a given list to get data from or a dict or what?

Comment: Your description of the problem is extremely vague. Can you show a *complete* example of *exactly* what `cities` might contain before the code, and *exactly* what `city_names` should contain afterwards? If not, then you do not have a question appropriate for Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. This is *not a discussion forum*, and therefore not the correct place to figure out what your instructor meant when writing out the assignment. The best place for that is your instructor's office hours. Next best is an actual discussion forum such as Reddit or Quora.

Comment: With your given code (after putting `[]` around the list) this prints, `['Buenos Aires', 'Toronto']` Isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
city_names = ['city1', 'city2'] # enter city names in this list
cities = []
for city in city_names:
    city_name = city + ' City'
    new_city_name = city.replace(city, city_name)
    cities.append(new_city_name)
print(cities)
```

(I am assuming that you have the required cities in a list due to the `city_names` list in your program)

If you want it from data similar to the above data, this is a modified version of my program

```
city_data = [{'City': 'Buenos Aires', 'Country': 'Argentina', 'Population': 2891000, 'Area': 4758}, {'City': 'Toronto', 'Country': 'Argentina', 'Population': 2891000, 'Area': 4758}]
city_names = []

for i in range(len(city_data)):
    city_names.append(city_data[i]['City'])


cities = []
for city in city_names:
    city_name = city + ' City'
    new_city_name = city.replace(city, city_name)
    cities.append(new_city_name)
print(cities)
```

Or maybe the question just wants you to do this:

```
city_data = [{'City': 'Buenos Aires', 'Country': 'Argentina', 'Population': 2891000, 'Area': 4758}, {'City': 'Toronto', 'Country': 'Argentina', 'Population': 2891000, 'Area': 4758}]
city_names = []

for i in range(len(city_data)):
    city_names.append(city_data[i]['City'])

print(city_names)
```

Comment: That last one worked perfectly. Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks so much. I'm going to study the other ways this was done as well.